# How to insert raw HTML in Pug file (not include external HTML file)

Tags: html, pug

So what I want is to put some multiline HTML into a Pug file and can't find anywhere how to do this.

Example:

```
html
    head

    body
        <div><a href="lala"> blabla </a></div>

        p hihuhohoo
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Pug *text* can include HTML. Just force it as text, and it should parse:

```
html
    head

    body
        | <div><a href="lala"> blabla </a></div>

        p hihuhohoo
```

Also, you were using backslashes, not forward slashes, to close elements.

Comment: Yeah the backslashes mistake was because I was making an example out of my head and haven't written actual html in forever :D

Comment: THIS MADE MY DAY. Can also be used with parameters as in `| !{paramName}`

Answer (score 29):

This is a tested example with passing variables with `raw html` to the pug file:

**yourSourceFile.js**

```
const p1 = 'This server uses a <a href="https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html" target="_blank">pug template</a> for the html output'
res.render('yourTemplateFile', { title: 'Hey', p1 })
```

**yourTemplateFile.pug**

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    p
      | !{p1}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to do this by encoding < and >

```html
div
  | &#60;script src="https://mydomain.io/script.js"&#x3E;&#60;/script&#x3E;
```