# Append pug compiled Content to pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

We generate inputfields based on tables. In the course of these the headers (title, unit) constant, but there may be multiple columns with the same input type (the simplest is a , but there als may be dynamic svgs), but variing content.

We would like to generate the tds content dynamically and append it to the template while rendering.

the input to the template is:

```
[{RowId: 'bla', RowUnit: '-', RowField: pug.compile('input')},
 {RowId: 'blub', RowUnit: 'm', RowField: pug.compile('span')}]
```

The template looks like this:

```
mixin addrow(rowdef)
    tr(id= rowdef.RowId)
        th= rowdef.RowId

        td()
            #{rowdef.RowField()}

        th= "[" + rowdef.RowUnit + "]"

table(class="dialogcontents")
    each rowdef in Contents
        +addrow(rowdef)

button(class="okbtn") Ok
button(class="cancelbtn") Cancel
```

but the above compiles like this:

```html
<table class="dialogcontents">
    <tr id="bla">
        <th>bla</th>
        <td><<input/>></<input/>></td>
             ^--- It looks like the tagname is "<input/>", so the function is compiled and applied as string then
        <th>[-]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="blub">
        <th>blub</th>
        <td><<span></span>></<span></span>></td>
             ^--- as above
        <th>[m]</th>
    </tr>
</table> 
<button class="okbtn">Ok</button>
<button class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
```

All in all the compiled function seems to be called twice. May I kindly ask for any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your broader goals are, but if you want to use a tag defined in your locals, you could set `RowField: 'span'` and then use tag interpolation:

```
#{rowdef.RowField} This is my span.
```

Which will render:

```
<span>This is my span.</span>
```

Comment: The broader goal is to append a dynamic content into a template, so the td's child node may be an <intput>, <span> or any other html tag, probably with childnodes

Comment: the Idea would be to forward the pug compiled function, so attributes can later be ammended, based on the local setting, but the function can be reused. Comparable to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779930/3559690), but not providing the complete html, but a function that would look like pug.compile('input(group=var)'), generating an output like <input group="1"/><input  group="2"/>