# jade to pug migration => Cannot read property 'every' of undefined on function call

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

We had a working jade render that could also include html that was rendered through a function.

```
// a function that is placed in the options object for jade.render
const someFunction = (para1, para2) {
  // some logic that gets a complete template from a source
  const template = (src) = `img.someClass(src=${src})`;
  // And returns the jade rendered variant of that template
  return jade.render(template, { src: para1 });
}

// # .jade file
div(class=(cover.hasCustomLogo ? 'cover coverWithCustomLogo' : 'cover'))
  img.logo(src=cover.logo)
  p.title=cover.title
  p.extension=cover.extension
  !{someFunction(cover.src)}
```

After the migration to pug, we got the error `Cannot read property 'every' of undefined`.

After some investigation, this lead to the `!{someFunction(cover.src)}` code inside the pug files. By changing the code to `#{someFunction(cover.src)}` the error did no longer occur, but Pug started adding opening and closing signs.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

rendered html before pug

```
<div class="cover">
  <img class="logo" src="test.jpg">
  <p class="title"></p>
  <p class="extension"></p>
  <img class="someClass" src="otherJPG.jpg">
</div>
```

rendered html after pug with interpolation

```
<div class="cover">
  <img class="logo" src="test.jpg">
  <p class="title"></p>
  <p class="extension"></p>
  <<img class="someClass" src="otherJPG.jpg">>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of trying and failing, the error was resolved as follows.

!{} does no longer work in pug as ! points to the doctype tag.

Solved it by using the | symbol. The solution then became

```
div(class=(cover.hasCustomLogo ? 'cover coverWithCustomLogo' : 'cover'))
  img.logo(src=cover.logo)
  p.title=cover.title
  p.extension=cover.extension
  | !{someFunction(cover.src)}
```

The solution came after reading the following stackoverflow question
[How to insert raw HTML in Pug file (not include external HTML file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107451/how-to-insert-raw-html-in-pug-file-not-include-external-html-file/27107508#comment101303744_27107508)