# Display String stored on mongo as HTML using PUG

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pug

I have some HTML stored in mongoDB in String format.

the db is 'db' and the property is 'profile' and the content is as below

```
"This is me and I want to be <strong>strong</strong>"
```

I am using PUG to display my views from the server and I am using this format

```
.profile
    p= user.profile
```

now my html output is as below which is expected

```
This is me and I want to be <strong>strong</strong>
```

But I want it to use the html tags to be used as HTML and display like this.

This is me and I want to be **strong**

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107451/how-to-insert-raw-html-in-pug-file-not-include-external-html-file

i think it resolve your problem

Comment: @DaniloMercadoOudalova Thanks a million!!! you saved my life!!!..:-)..

Comment: @DaniloMercadoOudalova  Your answer did resolve my issue but then I ran into another one.. can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644670/parsing-data-from-database-in-pug

Answer (score 0):

In your pug file:

```
.profile
    p!= user.profile
```

This will avoid pug escaping the HTML tags.

Comment: That didn't completely work for me.. and as there was a comment asking me to post a newer question for some reason.. I've added a new question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644670/parsing-data-from-database-in-pug