# Parsing data from database in PUG

Tags: html, mongodb, pug

I have this data in my mongo database which I can't control as data exported from my application to the database updates the html tags (I think the right term is 'encoding' but I am not sure)

```
&lt;div>This is some test profile text&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>Hop this prints fine&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;b>Hello&lt;/b>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>Testing&lt;/div>
```

In PUG When I try to parse it with

```
      .exhibitor-profile
          | !{exhibitor.profile}
```

it prints as below

```
<div>This is some test profile text<br /></div><div><br /></div><div>Hop this prints fine<br /></div><div><br /></div><div><b>Hello</b><br /></div><div><br /></div><div>Testing</div>
```

and if I use

```
      .exhibitor-profile
          | #{exhibitor.profile}
```

it prints as below

```
&lt;div>This is some test profile text&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>Hop this prints fine&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;b>Hello&lt;/b>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>&lt;br />&lt;/div>&lt;div>Testing&lt;/div>
```

basically the same as the data in the database.. but I want it to output as HTML..

How can I do this?

Comment: Your first example outputs HTML.

Comment: Sorry I meant I want to be rendered as HTML.. so I want to use this as HTML but it's displaying as 'text'... I am not sure if I am able to explain it properly.. maybe it's a very simple thing but I am a bit confused on how to use this text that I have as an HTML Element

Comment: In the database if I have the HTML then it renders as HTML .. if I use `|  !{exhibitor.profile}` with the database text as `<div><b>some text</b></div>` then the  some text would be bold and won't show me the `div` tags and the `b` tags but as the content in the database is `&ltl;div` it doesn't work the same way..

Comment: Are you using Node at the server?

Comment: @OldGeezer sorry for the late response.. but yes, I am using Node at the server... do you have any method to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node read on.

Install the [js-htmlencode](https://github.com/emn178/js-htmlencode) package:

```
npm install -S js-htmlencode
```

Then run your raw database output through the `htmlDecode` method once. You should do it in your server app before passing the data to your Pug script:

Server Javascript:

```
const htmlDecode = require("js-htmlencode").htmlDecode;
app.get("/htmldecode", (req, res) => {
  const raw = "&lt;h1>This is &lt;span style='color:red'>RED&lt;/span>!!&lt;/h1>"
  res.render("htmldecode", { raw: raw, decoded: htmlDecode(raw) })
});
```

htmldecode.pug:

```
html
  head
  body 
    h3 Html Decoding Twice
    p Using !: !{raw}
    p Using #: #{raw}
    p Final: !{decoded}
```

Actual output:

[image]

It should be noted that `!{raw}` does not render into `<h1>…`. It renders literally, ie to `&lt;h1>…`. It is the browser that shows `&lt;` as `<`.

Do take note of all the cautions that come with using the `!` operator.

Comment: @AlimBolar Does above work for you?

Comment: Will test this asap and get back to you